# messed up PATH and can't login

Tags: login

I was screwing around and trying to add some environment variables to my path.  I must have made a type or something because once I logged out, I could not lob back in.  I know I'm not on caps lock or anything and in fact if I type the wrong password I am informed of this.  However, when I type the correct password the desktop starts to load and then loops back to the login prompt.

There also no other users on the machine for me to log in as other than guest which does not have the right permissions for me to fix things.  Any ideas on where to go from here?

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you open up a login shell instead of logging into the desktop?. (I think the key combination is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>F1</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>).

Are you able to login this way and then correct the path issue from there?.

Comment: Just to clarify that's Alt+F1 OR Alt+F2 ,etc

Comment: the combo is ctrl+alt+f1 and no dice bro :(  the prompt from the console tells me the login is incorrect, so I have no idea whats going on

Comment: Can you login as root?

Comment: Hmmm... modifying the PATH variable shouldn't have affected your ability to login. The PATH variable just lists places to look for programs. You can just as easily access those programs by typing out their full paths.

Comment: yeah but What if you deleted your PATH, or wrote something like PATH ="PATH:HOME/bin" instead of PATH ="$PATH:HOME/bin" then you're env would be able to find any programs.

and no i never enabled root logon